# What does "...this began the transformation of Kankakee’s general education track into the College and Career Academy..." mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does the bolded part of the sentence mean?
Does it mean they began transforming Kankakee's general education track into the College and Career Academy? Could you please explain it?

> Each grade has a designated topic, paving the way for every student to explore and become familiar with a wide variety of career possibilities.
>
> **Three years ago, this began the transformation of Kankakee’s general education track into the College and Career Academy**, which is 100 percent focused on using with PBL to prepare students for future jobs.

[To Connect Classes to Careers, Consider Erasing Grade Levels](https://www.edsurge.com/news/2018-03-17-to-connect-classes-to-careers-consider-erasing-grade-levels)

Answer (score 1):

Let’s dissect the sentence:

**This began** is the first part. In the example, we don’t know what began what, but we only need to know the part that it began for the sentence to make sense (as long as it has proper context.
**the transformation of** comes next, which means first that there will be a noun following that has been changed in the way, and second the word “of” describes that a preposition will follow, becoming the noun that the transformation happened to.

**Kankakee’s general education track**, although it is made up of three words, describes one noun. **Kankakee’s** means that it is something that Kankakee has possession of. **general** is a sneaky adjective that may look like a noun, but it means in this case the overall or unabridged **education track**, which is the actual noun, and describes the path Kankakee will take through education and school and/or college.

Finally, **into the College and Career Academy** describes a specific noun that he/she is beginning.

So in summary, this (an untold event) began Kankakee’s overall journey through the education of the College and Career Academy.

Hope this helped!

Comment: @user70732 no problem good luck